# OneDrive errorneously appears with icon of Sharepoint storage

Tags: icons, office365, onedrive, sharepoint, cloud-storage

Please why my OneDrive account "B" (see below) appears as Sharepoint storage? How can I change it to standard OneDrive with dark blue cloud icon as seen at accounts "A" and "C"?

Account "B" is my personal *Office 365 Business Essentials* subscription and I have full access to *Office 365 Admin* app (I am the only admin and user there). Account "A" is also a OneDrive for business storage, administered by another company and its OneDrive icon is the expected one (dark blue cloud).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got fixed without any necessary action few weeks later. All the icons started to appear as expected.

I assume it was a problem in Office platform which was addressed by a fix.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, click File > Account, under User Information, remove the OneDrive for Business account and SharePoint Online account for Account B. Also click Switch Account to sign in Account B, then sign out it.

Then open Registry Editor, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities` ,
delete the key for Account B.

Restart Excel 2016, go to File > Account, make sure there is no AccountB information and services listed there. Then Add a service to add OneDrive for Business service and SharePoint Online service for AccountB, check if the icons are displayed correctly or not.

Comment: Thank you. The problem got fixed by itself a few weeks later. Obviously it was some problem in Office platform which they later fixed.